# hive data has been overwrited while using insert into A select xx from B where?

Tags: java, insert, hive, overwrite

I have two tables in hive, when I use SQL:

```
insert into A partition(a='x1') select * from B where a='x1'.
```

It overwrites data in `partition(a='x1')` of table `A`.

Why does this SQL overwrites data ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the cause by myself.
***Table names must be simple and lower case ONLY.***
You can read the jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3939